# FormatTime returns todays date instead of the actual date of the variable

Tags: autohotkey

I extract a timestamp from a regex. This will be in the raw format: `YYYYMMDD`

There isn't a timestamp, from the documentation, that seems to be acceptable. I tried with and without.

I just want to convert it to `MMMDD` however, it just outputs today's date in everything that I've tried. So I must be missing something major.

```
regexmatch(file_name, "O) (202[0-9][0]?[1]?\d{1}\d{2})", diag_date)
; diag_date[1] in all my testing has been 20200831
msgbox % "Unformatted Date: " diag_date[1] 
FormatTime, diag_date, diag_date[1], MMMdd
msgbox % "Formatted Date: " diag_date
```

--Simpler test--

```
unformatted := "20200831"
FormatTime, formatted, unformatted, MMMdd
msgbox % formatted
; still outputs today's date.
```

The last msgbox keeps returning today's date even though the matched date is another date (e.g. 20200831)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not forcing an expression on the second parameter. So it just interprets you passing in an invalid timestamp.

```
unformatted := "20200831"
FormatTime, formatted, % unformatted, MMMdd
msgbox % formatted
```